# Shared pointer dereferencing error

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr, operator-precedence

Java guy here trying to get my head around C++, specifically *shared pointers*. I'm using the Point Cloud Library to do some surface work. The PCL library contains `IndicesPtr` which according to the documentation is a *shared pointer* on a `std::vector`.

How do I access the vector from the pointer? I have tried dereferencing with

```
pcl::IndicesPtr sample(new std::vector<int>());
...
for (int i = 0; i < *sample.size(); i++) { ... }
```

as per the documentation here https://theboostcpplibraries.com/boost.smartpointers-shared-ownership. Compiling then gives me the error

```
error: no member named 'size' in 'boost::shared_ptr<std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> > >'; did you mean to use '->' instead of '.'?
    for (int i = 0; i < *sample.size(); i++) {
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Just write `(*sample).size()` instead.

Comment: Oh, aren't I a noob. Thanks.

Comment: or: `std::for_each( sample->cbegin(), sample->cend(), [] (int i) { ... } )`;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), `operator.` has higher precedence than `operator*`. So `*sample.size()` is same as `*(sample.size())`. That's why the compiler tried to tell you that you can't invoke `size()` on a `boost::shared_ptr` directly.

You can add parentheses to specify precedence explicitly, e.g. `(*sample).size()`; or as the compiler suggested, change it to `sample->size()`.

Answer (score 3):

It should either be `(*sample).size()` because `operator .` has higher precedence over dereference `operator *` or just `sample->size()`.